# combobox php mysql delete value

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, sql-delete

> require 'open.php';
>       $query4 = "SELECT * FROM posto_emissao,cliente, conta WHERE idCliente = '".$_SESSION['usuarioClienteID']."' AND
>   conta.Cliente_idCliente = cliente.idCliente AND cliente.idCliente =
>   posto_emissao.Cliente_idCliente";
>       $resultado = @mysql_query($query4,$dbConnect);
>       $resultado2 = @mysql_query($query4,$dbConnect);

This conn things are working fine! My problem comes here:
**I want to select a ID from a populated combobox and delete them from DB**

Here's my form: (part of it)

```
echo '<form name ="apagar" method="post" action="apagape.php" id="peform">';
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo' <li class="category">';
        echo '<label>Posto de emissão:</label>';
        echo '<select name="eliminar_PE">';
        echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccione um posto</option>';
    if ($resultado2 === FALSE)
            echo "<p>Não foi possivel resolver a query.</p>" . "<p> Erro: " . mysql_errno($dbConnect) . ": " . mysql_error($dbConnect) . "</p>";
            else 
            {
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2))
            {                  
            echo'<option value="'.$row2['idPosto_Emissao'].'">'.$row2['idPosto_Emissao'].'</option>';
            }
```

> echo'';      echo '
> ';        echo '
> ';
>           echo '
>
> ';
>           echo '';       echo '';
>           echo ''; mysql_close($dbConnect);

Here's my apagape.php: (part of it)

> require 'open.php';       $query5 = "DELETE FROM posto_emissao WHERE
>   idPosto_Emissao = '".$_POST['IdPosto_Emissao']."'";
>             $result5=@mysql_query($query5,$dbConnect);      if ($result5 ===
>   FALSE)        {           echo "
>
> Não foi possivel resolver a query.
>
> " . "
>
> Erro: " . mysql_errno($dbConnect) . ": " . mysql_error($dbConnect) .
>   "
>
> ";       }       else {      header("Location: index.php");      }
>         mysql_close($dbConnect);

**PROBLEM: Nothing happens, delete fails :|**

What i need to do?

Comment: .$_POST['IdPosto_Emissao']. seems empty :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a delete variable. I delete database entries like this by creating a dynamic url

```
<a href="delete.php?=<?php echo $var;?>">click</a>
```

I would then pull down an array on my *delete.php* page and have it look for that url variable, and match the record and delete it. returning back to the original page.